# MSGraph API returning messages with no format on specific shared EmailAddress/Mailbox

Tags: c#, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

We have an desktop application that uses MSGraph v4.35 to get Email Messages from specific shared mailboxes, it gets the messages and creates a text file with the body content, it then processes the mail content to extract some information, this considering the HTML Format of the email.

The issue comes when in specific Mailbox, mails are extracted with no format. Therefore, the data extraction from the text file is not done correctly.

Expected Text File Result:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<br>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Actual result:

```
<html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>
```

I have validated the code, the header specifies to get HTML format

```
var mailResults = await client.Users[DptMail].MailFolders.Inbox.ChildFolders.Messages
                                .Request()
                                .Header("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type='text'")
                                .GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I try replicating the issue, dropping the mishandled messages on other mailbox, but the results are as expected on different mailboxes.